# How do I validate a large integer in testNG?

Tags: testng

I have the following validation in my script:

```
.body("entity.segments[0].segmentEnds[0].publicNoticeDate",equalTo("1514844812000"))
```

I'm getting the following, highly confusing failure:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path entity.segments[0].segmentEnds[0].publicNoticeDate doesn't match.
Expected: 1514844812000
  Actual: 1514844812000
```

I think you can see my frustration immediately.  If I take out the quotes:

```
.body("entity.segments[0].segmentEnds[0].publicNoticeDate",equalTo(1514844812000))
```

Then Eclipse tells me that the value is out of range for an integer.

I have tried replacing *equalTo()* with *is()* both with and without quotes, and have had no satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plausible explanation.

I am guessing that `entity.segments[0].segmentEnds[0].publicNoticeDate` is returning a number (perhaps a `Long`). So when you are doing

`.body("entity.segments[0].segmentEnds[0].publicNoticeDate",equalTo("1514844812000"))`

You are comparing a `Long` with a String. The equality check happens via a call to "equals()" method and since they are not equal the test fails. But the error message is confusing for you because there's no distinct way to show that you were expecting the string `"1514844812000"` but you got back a `Long` value `1514844812000`.

To fix this, try changing

`.body("entity.segments[0].segmentEnds[0].publicNoticeDate",equalTo(1514844812000)`

To 
`.body("entity.segments[0].segmentEnds[0].publicNoticeDate",equalTo(1514844812000L))`

*Notice how I have added an "L" at the end of the number to signify that this is a Long integer.*

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the right thing.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @FredWolke - Can you please help accept my answer, if it helped with your question ?